# Retrieve full deleted document of delete operation using pymongo change stream

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I've just started getting my hands dirty with MongoDB and Python, so bear with me on this one.

The scenario is as follows:

- I have a MongoDB collection and using pymongo's [watch](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.watch) I listen to changes that occur.
- For the purposes of explaining my problem, let's say that I can only react to anything that happens after the change in the collection.

The problem comes when there is a delete operation happening in the collection. Change stream only returns the _id of the deleted document, while I am looking for a way of getting the full detailed document (much like how it's being return when you insert a new document).

Is this even possible and if yes, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no, it's not possible to do that in the current version on MongoDB (4.4)

Change streams are very useful, but they can only tell you what happened post-event. For those from a SQL background used to triggers where you can get the "before" and "after" view, this might be frustrating; but it's just the way it is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's what I found out with my research but I wanted to make sure. Cheers!

Comment: If you really really had to do it you could maybe configure a delayed replica and then query that when you get a delete on the primary. But I haven't tried it and YMMV (a lot).

Comment: Thanks again for your comment Belly Buster. I may have a look at this as it does sound like something I can work with. Cheers!